# NativeScript IOS project.pbxproj not found

Tags: ios, nativescript

I am trying to run the hello world nativescript app using the command `"tns run ios"` but i am getting `"Unable to apply changes on device: <device id>. Error is: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/<path_to_project>/NativeTest/platforms/ios/NativeTest.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj'."`. Running it in Xcode works. I really ran out of ideas . Also, i checked and the file is actually there

Answer (score 3):

After hours of time spent with this issue i found a fix, so maybe my answer would help somebody else. The issue was caused by me setting in XCode the dev team in the project. After i set the team project for the current project, i create a new project and it automatically got the team id i set at the old project without my intervention and now it works without errors. Yay

Comment: I couldn't quite understand your fix, however resolution on my end was to delete platforms/ios folder and rerun $ tns platform add ios. I believe $ tns platform clean ios might also work for some cases.

Comment: @KING you're my hero

Answer (score 2):

`ns clean` did it for me like it told me to do  `The platforms/ios folder appears to be invalid. If the build fails, run 'ns clean' and rebuild the app.`

I was running `npm run ios`